# Mongodb : How to find out all the documents which contains location?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have collection tolls in mongodb with following attributes

```
{

    title: {type: String, required:true},

    location: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2d'
    },
    radius: {type: Number, required:true},
    fee: {type: Number, required:true},

}
```

how to write a query using nodejs which finds the current toll a vehicle is in. We have the current location (Latitude and Longitude) of the vehicle.

Comment: look into $near https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check bellow link to know in details,

[mongodb-get-document-in-nearby-order](https://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2018/08/mongodb-get-document-in-nearby-order.html)

Answer (score 0):

For these query to run `2dsphere` index is required,

```
Tolls.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [12.2566,56.1455] },
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            maxDistance: 1000,                      // Radius of area
            spherical: true,                        // In meter
        }
    }
]
```

And below is schema which needs to be changed,

```
location: {
    type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
    coordinates: [Number]
}
```